# How to test if futures run sequentially in Scala?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, asynchronous, future

Suppose I have this methods:

```
def callApis(f1, f2, f3):Future[Result] {
    for {
        a <- Future { f1 }
        b <- Future { f2 }
        c <- Future { f3 }
    } yield Result(a,b,c)
}
```

If you are familiar with scala you will know that lines in the for block will execute sequentially. More specific, a will be calculated first. Then when we have the result for a, the code will calculate b. Then when we have the result for b, the code will calculate c.

**My question is, how can you write a UNIT TEST that ensures that a always be computed before calculating b, and b always be computed before calculating c?** My fear is if someone doesn't know much about how futures work in scala. They can accidentally make this code to run asynchronously.

I mean people can **accidentally** do something like this, this makes a,b,c to be calculated asynchronously **(which I don't want people to do)**:

```
def callApis(f1, f2, f3):Future[Result] {
    val fut1 = Future { f1 }
    val fut2 = Future { f2 }
    val fut3 = Future { f3 }

    for {
        a <- fut1
        b <- fut2
        c <- fut3
    } yield Result(a,b,c)
}
```

Comment: Test it with an execution context that fails if a second task is submitted before the first finishes. If the futures kick off more futures, then the bookkeeping is harder and you should use explicit coordination such as a countdown latch, and let them use the second syntax if they want.

Comment: @som-snytt I understand your resolution. But we can not sure the code runs sequentially if the second task submitted after the first finishes. I mean we can only sure when the second task start after the first finishes. Which I don't know how to check.

Comment: I guess it's not a solution here because you need Future, but in case there is no such restriction, I would suggest to use any of existing IOs instead of Future (eg Cats Effect). This would give you the guarantee out of the box, so you won't need a test.

Comment: @highDopamine On top of the valuable comments and answers that you received already, I'd like to point out that testing the behaviour that comes from a design decision of a library you use feels a bit weird to me. That's like testing that mockito really returns some value when you tell it to return some value. If you have a problem with Futures behaving this way (and I'm glad you recognized it), how about investing into effect types like cats IO, Monix Task or ZIO? I know not every project can afford that, but maybe yours can.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try defining a single-threaded execution context and require it in blocks that should execute serially. For example,

```
trait SerialExecutionContext extends ExecutionContext {
  val singleThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1, (r: Runnable) => new Thread(r, s"single-thread-pool"))
  val serialEc = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(singleThreadPool)
  override def execute(runnable: Runnable): Unit = serialEc.execute(runnable)
  override def reportFailure(cause: Throwable): Unit = serialEc.reportFailure(cause)
}


def callApis()(implicit ec: SerialExecutionContext): Future[Result] = {
  val fut1 = Future { ...doSomething... }
  val fut2 = Future { ...doSomething... }
  val fut3 = Future { ...doSomething... }

  for {
    a <- fut1
    b <- fut2
    c <- fut3
  } yield Result(a,b,c)
}
```

Now `callApis` can evaluate only if we can prove at compile time there exists a serial execution context. Since within the body we have only one thread available futures are forced to start only after the previous one finished.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this seems not related to my question. I edited my question to be more clear. Please check.

Comment: This would be a solution to help you sleep at night, except for the part where there is only one thread. We don't know what doSomething does, or if there are other tasks to run. Just wanted to say it is related to the question, but apparently an extended discussion is required to establish the requirements. Probably, as the other comments, a different abstraction is needed.